# Directory listing with wildcards in C

Tags: c, linux, filter, directory, scandir

Is there a ready-made function in `C` that can list the contents of a directory using `wildcards` to filter out file names, for example, the equivalent of:

```
echo [!b]????
```

which shows the names of directory entries that are four characters long and do not start with "b"?

I know I can use `scandir`, but then, I need to provide my own filter function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
int filter(const struct dirent *entry)
{
    if (strlen(entry->d_name) == 4 && entry->d_name[0] != 'b') return 1;
    else return 0;
}
void main(void)
{
    struct dirent **list;
    int           count;
    count=scandir(".", &list, filter, alphasort)-1;
    if (count < 0)
        puts("Cannot open directory");
    else
        for (; count >= 0; count--)
            puts(list[count]->d_name);
    free(list);
}
```

Honestly, I am seriously considering actually calling `shell` to do it for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char buffer[1024];
    fp=popen("echo [!b]???", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        puts("Failed to run command.");
    else
        while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), fp) != NULL)
            puts(buffer);
    pclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: what is a problem to use regex inside function filter?

Comment: I need `ls` `wildcard` behavior, which is not quite like regex. For example: `*.jpg` means "any number of any character, foloowed by dot-jpg", while in regex, it would mean "any number of nothing, followed by one character of any kind, followed by jpg". Regex equivalent is then `.*\.jpg`, isn't it?

Comment: You may be looking for the `glob` function. `man 3 glob`.

Comment: Have you looked at `fnmatch()`, `wordexp()` or `glob()`?

Comment: Thank you! Both `fnmatch` and `glob` are going to be useful for different scenarios that I have.

Comment: Have you looked at popen() and read() ?

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned in the comments the `glob()` function would be pretty good for this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <glob.h>

int
main (void)
{
    int i=0;
    glob_t globbuf;

    if (!glob("[!b]????", 0, NULL, &globbuf)) {
        for (i=0;  i <globbuf.gl_pathc; i++) { 
            printf("%s ",globbuf.gl_pathv[i]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        globfree(&globbuf);
    } else 
        printf("Error: glob()\n");
}
```